# YQL query failing suddenly

Tags: csv, yahoo, yql

We are utilizing `YQL` to retrieve external data from a CSV. Lately the query has been returning `null` across the board and we can't figure out why.

Did Yahoo update their API?

**Query**

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from csv where url IN ('http://www.iso-ne.com/transform/csv/fiveminlmp/current?type=prelim') AND col1 IN ('4014')
```

**Store**

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from yql.storage where name='store://ueZTPNC1PAVBw7lBz8FWNu'
```

**Code**

```
<execute><![CDATA[ 
   y.log("Version 4.1");
    function getTimeQueryParam(){
      var d = new Date();
      var year = d.getFullYear();
      var month = d.getMonth();
      var day = d.getDate();
      var hr = d.getHours();
      var min = d.getMinutes();
      var sec = d.getSeconds();
      return '' + year + month + day + hr + min + sec;
    }
        //selects the current interval of LMP prices from ISO-NE
   var newData = null; 
   newData = y.query("select * from csv where url IN ('http://www.iso-ne.com/transform/csv/fiveminlmp/current?type=prelim') AND col1 IN ('4014')");
   newData = newData.results.row;
   if(newData == null || newData == ''){
        y.log("No New Data. Retry");
        newData = y.query("select * from csv where url IN ('http://www.iso-ne.com/transform/csv/fiveminlmp/current?type=prelim') AND col1 IN ('4014')");
        newData = newData.results.row;
   }    
   y.log("Current time interval: " + newData.col2);
        //selects the data stored in our YQL storage table for this tieline     

    var oldData = null; 
   oldData = y.query("select * from yql.storage where name='store://ueZTPNC1PAVBw7lBz8FWNu'");

   var results = oldData.results.result;
    y.log("results = oldData.results.result: " + results);
    var resultsJSON = y.xmlToJson(results);
    y.log("data JSON: " + y.jsToString(resultsJSON));

    var data = resultsJSON.result.value;
    var count = data.length;


    //checks to make sure the current time interval has not been added to store
   if(newData.col2 != data[data.length-1].col2){
        //24 = MAX_NUMBER of intervals we want to keep
        //delete oldest entries
        y.log("Oldest time interval before delete: " + data[0].col2);        
        if(count > 24){
            var deleteNum = count - 24;
            for(d = 0; d < deleteNum; d++) data.shift();
        }
        y.log("Oldest time interval after delete: " +data[0].col2);
        //adds current interval to store
        data[data.length] = newData;     
   }
        //creates JSONString from data Array, only text format can be stored in YQL storage 
   var txt = '[';
   for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    txt = txt + '{"col0":"' + data[i].col0 + '", ';
    txt = txt + '"col1":"' + data[i].col1 + '", ';
    txt = txt + '"col2":"' + data[i].col2 + '", ';
    txt = txt + '"col3":"' + data[i].col3 + '", ';
    txt = txt + '"col4":"' + data[i].col4 + '", ';
    txt = txt + '"col5":"' + data[i].col5 + '", ';
    txt = txt + '"col6":"' + data[i].col6 + '"} ';
    if(i+1 < data.length)txt = txt + ', ';
   }    
   txt = txt + ']';
        //updates the YQL Storage Table with new data set       
   var status = y.query("update yql.storage set value='" + txt + "'where name='" + update + "'");
   y.log(status);
        //pulls newly updated data for queries on this YQL table
   var updatedData = y.query("select * from yql.storage where name='store://ueZTPNC1PAVBw7lBz8FWNu'");
   response.object = updatedData.results.result;   
      ]]></execute>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo just stopped support for `YQL`. At least their `html extract api`. One thing you can do is to run the YQL function from part of community Open Data tables.

For instance for extracting `html` instead of:

```
select * from html
```

You can use:

```
select * from htmlstring
```

[Read here](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=show%20tables&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select%20%2A%20from%20htmlstring%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yahoo.com%2F'%20and%20xpath%3D'%2F%2Fa')

Comment: Was there ever a release or notification saying that support was dropped?

Comment: @PT_C Yeah, They dropped support for `html` but `htmlstring` still working since it yahoo's developer community that support that

Comment: Try to run your query in your browser and result will say, Yahoo has stopped support `html`

Comment: Any alternative to yql for web scraping?

Comment: @Sinchan There is some options out there, you can find by searching, otherwise I would recommend you to build your own scrapper *(server side)*. There are many web scrapers for each language/framework. I would also combine that with `ajax` to get realtime results if you are looking for realtime. If you use `ruby on rails`. I can write the answer if you submit a question.

Comment: Is there any client side web scraper using js/jquery/angularjs?

Comment: Im sure there is. What is your application based on? *(language & framework)*

Comment: php. Codeigniter

Comment: @Sinchan Yeah there are some options for doing this server-side. As said Im on ruby on rails but I may have some solutions for that that might help you. If you submit a question and send me the link I will add the answer there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44881500/how-to-scrape-web-content-using-js-angularjs-jquery-other-than-yql-any-alternat?noredirect=1#comment76741170_44881500

Comment: @user6589814 why does it matter if YQL stopped supporting `html` if I'm using `select * from yql.storage`?